# Combining multiple conditions from multiple columns in to a new column

Tags: r, if-statement, multiple-columns

I can't seem to get my code to work when I want to create a new column with a single integer from multiple conditions from multiple columns.

I have 4 vars: `pun1, pun2, pun3, pun4.` I want to transform these rows depending on the conditions to a new column ( `pun_severity_out` ) and give it a 1 if all conditions are true. Whenever a condition is not true, the integer should change to `pun_severity_out = 0`

The thing here is that pun1 and pun2 are grouped together, and so are pun3 and pun4.

Whenever there's a NA, this means that that person has been evaluated by others ( you can't punish yourself ).
Since these Ss are grouped, we have an ingroup and outgroup. So if `pun1 == NA`, this means that the outgroup is `pun3` & `pun4`. For clarity, if `pun3 == NA`, then the outgroup is `pun1` & `pun2`.

What I want to accomplish is that all values of 4 or higher for **both outgroup members** to be merged into a single value, 1. But only if there's an NA present in the other group, because we specifically want outgroup members.

**Edit: sample data**

```
   UniqueSS subject group       part round  treatment pun1 pun2 pun3 pun4 severity_pun_out
1        11       1     1 punishment     0 homogenous   NA    0    0    0                0
2        12       2     1 punishment     0 homogenous    0   NA    0    0                0
3        13       3     1 punishment     0 homogenous    0    0   NA    0                0
4        14       4     1 punishment     0 homogenous    0    0    1   NA                0
5        11       1     1 punishment     1 homogenous   NA    0    0    0                0
6        12       2     1 punishment     1 homogenous    0   NA    0    0                0
7        13       3     1 punishment     1 homogenous    0    0   NA    0                0
8        14       4     1 punishment     1 homogenous    0    0    0   NA                0
9        11       1     1 punishment     2 homogenous   NA    0    0    0                0
10       12       2     1 punishment     2 homogenous    0   NA    5    4                1
```

My best attempt is this, but this gives NAs when using more ifelse() inside the same statement:

`df5$severity_pun_out <- with(df5, ifelse(pun1 == NA & pun3 >= 4 & pun4 >= 4, 1, ifelse(pun2 == NA & pun3 >= 4 & pun4 >= 4, 1, ifelse(pun3 == NA & pun1 >= 4 & pun2 >= 4, 1, ifelse(pun4 == NA & pun1 >= 4 & pun2 >= 4, 1, 0 )))))`

1) If `pun1 == NA` then `pun3` & `pun4` is the outgroup.

2) Then if `pun3` & `pun4` have their values equal or higher than 4, put down a 1 in that row for the (new) `pun_severity_out` column.

I think the NAs are causing some of the ruckus, but it's just a condition to be met. I am not sure how to solve this, because I am just calling for a `1` not a transformation of any NAs.

Should I call the specific row with that specific NA and then apply the outgroup transformation? I am assuming that's what I am doing with ifelse(), because we specifically use the row with that specific NA.

The code (or function) is preferably short, simple and general applicable and does not interact with the dataset (except for possibly making *pun_severity_out* column ). I might want to change the cut-off value to 3, so altering the code shouldn't be more than changing a value.

I don't often use dplyr, but if it's that much better/easier/faster I'll use it.

### Additional question

Bonus points if you can single out the ingroup `pun(X)` from the 4 variables and put its integer in to a new column called `pun_severity_in`. As in, if `pun1 == NA`, add `pun2` in the row of the `pun_severity_in` column.

### Used sources

[How can I create a column based on multiple conditions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34642061/how-can-i-create-a-column-based-on-multiple-conditions)

[How do I create a new column based on multiple conditions from multiple columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39405628/how-do-i-create-a-new-column-based-on-multiple-conditions-from-multiple-columns)

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/115162/filtering-a-dataframe-in-r-based-on-multiple-conditions

**Thanks in advance**

Comment: It would greatly help your question to show sample data, and then the output you expect based on that input.  I don't completely follow your question.

Comment: Added the first 10 lines :)

Comment: Use `is.na(pun)` instead of `pun == NA`. `NA == NA` returns `NA`, not `TRUE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `==` for testing `NA`, you'll just get `NA` back. Use `is.na` instead. Try this:

```
df5$severity_pun_out <-
  with(df5, ifelse(
    is.na(pun1) &
      pun3 >= 4 &
      pun4 >= 4,
    1,
    ifelse(
      is.na(pun2) &
        pun3 >= 4 &
        pun4 >= 4,
      1,
      ifelse(
        is.na(pun3) &
          pun1 >= 4 &
          pun2 >= 4,
        1,
        ifelse(is.na(pun4) &
                 pun1 >= 4 &
                 pun2 >= 4, 1, 0
        )
      )
    )
  )
)
```

A simpler alternative would be to combine the paired `is.na` conditions with `|`, like this:

```
df5$severity_pun_out <-
  with(df5, ifelse(
    (is.na(pun1) | is.na(pun2)) &
      pun3 >= 4 &
      pun4 >= 4,
    1,
    ifelse((is.na(pun3) | is.na(pun4)) &
             pun1 >= 4 &
             pun2 >= 4,
           1, 0)
  ))
```

In `dplyr`, you could use `case_when` which *can* be simpler than `ifelse`, but is a matter of style.

Comment: I tinkered a bit with is.na(), but had no success. It all works now, thanks :)
If I may ask, is there a shorter/better way of writing this?

Comment: Thanks! I'll have a look at dplyr too. I often cross it when I look for solutions, thanks again.