# Matching values in multiple columns in R based on condition

Tags: r, if-statement, string-matching

Say I have a datafame `df`

```
resident    faculty    submittedBy    match    caseID    phase

george      sally      george         1        george_1  pre
george      sally      sally          0        george_1  pre
george      sally      george         1        george_1  intra
jane        carl       jane           1        jane_1    pre
jane        carl       carl           0        jane_1    pre
jane        carl       carl           0        jane_1    intra
```

and I want to add a column `df$response` to this dataframe according to the following parameters (I'm thinking I need a set of nested ifelses, but I'm struggling to execute it correctly):

For a given row X, if `df$match` = 1,

print "1" in `df$response` if:

***any row*** in `df$match` where `df$match` = 0 has the same contents in `df$caseID`, `df$faculty`, and `df$phase` as row X. Otherwise print "0".

So the output should be this:

```
response

1
0
0
1
0
0
```

because only the first and fourth rows contain values for which there are matches in `df$caseID`, `df$faculty`, and `df$phase` for both a row where `df$match` = 1 and a row where `df$match` = 0.

Comment: im not sure I follow...can you make the criteria into separate bullet points to distinguish between them better and just be a bit clearer in your wording? Maybe exlicity talk through why the first few responses are the way they are.

Comment: @soosus have you seen this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34642061/how-can-i-create-a-column-based-on-multiple-conditions)?

Comment: @RAB I have adjusted accordingly

Comment: how do row 1/4 match? row1: `faculty = sally`, `caseID = george_1` and `phase = pre`. none of these match? I cannpt follow your logic. What are they suppose to be matching?

Comment: @RAB i'm looking for a row X where match = 1 and then seeing if any row where match = 0 has the same values as row X for phase, faculty, and caseID (rows 1 and 2 fit this criterion because one of them has match = 1 and the other has match = 0 but phase, faculty, and caseID are the same)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I'd do it

```
# read the data
test <- read.table(text = 'resident    faculty    submittedBy    match    caseID    phase
                   george      sally      george         1        george_1  pre
                   george      sally      sally          0        george_1  pre
                   george      sally      george         1        george_1  intra
                   jane        carl       jane           1        jane_1    pre
                   jane        carl       carl           0        jane_1    pre
                   jane        carl       carl           0        jane_1    intra', header=T)

# create the response
resp <- logical(0)

# iterate over each loop
for (rr in 1:nrow(test)){
  if (test$match[rr] == 0){
    resp[rr] <- 0
  }
  else{
    tmp <- rbind(test[-rr, c('faculty', 'caseID', 'phase')],  # add the onto the end
                 test[rr, c('faculty', 'caseID', 'phase')])   # test if line is duplicated
    resp[rr] <- ifelse(duplicated(tmp)[nrow(tmp)], 1, 0)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

We can use `data.table` methods.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), grouped by 'caseID', 'faculty', 'phase', get the length of `unique` elements of `match` check if it is equal to 2 and create a binary column ('response'), For values where 'match' is 0', assign the 'response' to 0

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, response := +((uniqueN(match) == 2) & match != 0), 
                  .(caseID, faculty, phase)][]
#   resident faculty submittedBy match   caseID phase response
#1:   george   sally      george     1 george_1   pre        1
#2:   george   sally       sally     0 george_1   pre        0
#3:   george   sally      george     1 george_1 intra        0
#4:     jane    carl        jane     1   jane_1   pre        1
#5:     jane    carl        carl     0   jane_1   pre        0
#6:     jane    carl        carl     0   jane_1 intra        0
```

---

Or using `base R` with `ave`

```
with(df1,+( match != 0 & ave(match, caseID, faculty, phase, 
         FUN = function(x) length(unique(x))) == 2))
#[1] 1 0 0 1 0 0
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(resident = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), 
.Label = c("george", 
"jane"), class = "factor"), faculty = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("carl", "sally"), class = "factor"), 
    submittedBy = structure(c(2L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("carl", 
    "george", "jane", "sally"), class = "factor"), match = c(1L, 
    0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L), caseID = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L), .Label = c("george_1", "jane_1"), class = "factor"), 
    phase = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("intra", 
    "pre"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Comment: love the `ave` solution, very succinct. are you able to explain how exaclty it works? never seen it used that way

Comment: @RAB `ave` can be used as a replacement for group by + mutate from dplyr or `[, := , by =]` in data.table.  The way it works is we pass the first argument as the column/vector to modify, here it is `match`, and the subsequent arguments are all grouping variable, until the `FUN`.  If we dont pass any `FUN`, by default takes the `mean`.  Good thing is that it won't change the original order.  In this case, we are passing anonymous function call to check the `length` of `unique` elements of `match` in each of these groups.  The `match != 0 &`  is to replace values  0 in match to 0

Answer (score 2):

Indexing using `[]` is much faster, and less costly on your machine

```
df <- data.frame(
  "resident" = c("george","george","george","jane","jane","jane"),
  "faculty" = c("sally","sally","sally","carl","carl","carl"),
  "submittedBy" = c("george","sally","george","jane","carl","carl"),
  "match" = c(1,0,1,1,0,0),
  "caseID" = c("george_1","george_1","george_1","jane_1","jane_1","jane_1"),
  "phase" = c("pre","pre","intra","pre","pre","intra"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
  )

response <- NULL

for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  response[i] <- ifelse(
    df$match[i] == 0, 0,
    ifelse(
      any(paste(df$caseID,df$faculty,df$phase,sep="")[df$match == 0] == 
            paste(df$caseID,df$faculty,df$phase,sep="")[i]),
      1, 0
    )
  )
}

response
[1] 1 0 0 1 0 0
```

Comment: I keep getting a "Error: unexpected '}' in:" error for this code

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have only 1 and 0 values in `match`, one way with `dplyr` would be to check for every `caseID`, `faculty` and `phase` if there is two distinct values in `match` (1 and 0) and replace the `response` to 0 where `match` is 0.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(caseID, faculty, phase) %>%
  mutate(response = as.integer(n_distinct(match) == 2),
         response = replace(response, match == 0, 0))

#  resident faculty submittedBy match caseID   phase response
#  <chr>    <chr>   <chr>       <dbl> <chr>    <chr>    <dbl>
#1 george   sally   george          1 george_1 pre          1
#2 george   sally   sally           0 george_1 pre          0
#3 george   sally   george          1 george_1 intra        0
#4 jane     carl    jane            1 jane_1   pre          1
#5 jane     carl    carl            0 jane_1   pre          0
#6 jane     carl    carl            0 jane_1   intra        0
```

Answer (score 2):

Another *data.table* approach. Join on the key variables and check if the values are not in the `match==0` set:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat)

dat[, response := match==1]
dat[!dat[match==0], on=c("caseID","faculty","phase"), response := FALSE]

dat
#   resident faculty submittedBy match   caseID phase response
#1:   george   sally      george     1 george_1   pre     TRUE
#2:   george   sally       sally     0 george_1   pre    FALSE
#3:   george   sally      george     1 george_1 intra    FALSE
#4:     jane    carl        jane     1   jane_1   pre     TRUE
#5:     jane    carl        carl     0   jane_1   pre    FALSE
#6:     jane    carl        carl     0   jane_1 intra    FALSE
```